# foreach() function causing errors

Tags: php, html, foreach

I wrote a function which calls an array from table

```
function fetchoperator($operator_type)
{
    global $mysqli; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT 
        id,
        operator_name   
    FROM gb_operators WHERE operator_type = ?
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $operator_type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$operator_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        $row = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    if(!empty($row))
    {
        return ($row);
    }
    else
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Now in main page

```
$oprtor=fetchoperator(1);
```

Now coming to the html page

```
<select id="MPOperator" name="opr" class="form-control" required>
        <?php foreach($oprtor as $v2) {
            echo "<option value=".$v2['id'].">".$v2['operator_name']."</option>"; } ?>                                       
            </select>
```

Now when i am using without foreach() function i am getting a value of last row of the table but when i am using with foreach function i am getting an Output as V

but it should display 14 columns. Please help me out with the error!!!!

Comment: Do you understand that `$row = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name)` __overwrites__ value of `$row` every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not filling an array, you are over writing a scalar variable a lot of times

```
function fetchoperator($operator_type)
{
    global $mysqli; 
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id, operator_name   
                              FROM gb_operators 
                              WHERE operator_type = ?
    ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $operator_type);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id,$operator_name);
    while ($stmt->fetch()){
        // error here
        //$row = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name);

        $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name);
    }
    $stmt->close();
    if(!empty($row)) {
        return $row;
    } else {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks got the output

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the `$row` variable. This is why you are only getting the last row. Convert it to `$row[]` which will push the rows into the `$row` array.

Do this

```
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use array_push() to add a new values in array. in your case. you are just set the array a new values.

```
array_push($row, array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name));
```

Answer (score 0):

You are overwriting the previous row each time.

Instead, you should be adding each row:

```
$row = [];
while ($stmt->fetch()){
    $row[] = array('id' => $id, 'operator_name' => $operator_name); 
}
return $row;
```